# Migration in PostgreSQL 11 from PostGIS 2.4 to 2.5 fails

Tags: postgis, migration

This is my attempt to migrate the data:

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
WARNING:  'postgis.backend' is already set and cannot be changed until you reconnect
ERROR:  operator does not exist: gidx public.&& geography
LINE 1: SELECT $2 OPERATOR(public.&&) $1;
                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT $2 OPERATOR(public.&&) $1;
```

More details:

- CentOS 7
- select postgis_full_version();

  POSTGIS="2.4.7 r17330" PGSQL="93" (procs need upgrade for use with "110") GEOS="3.7.1-CAP
  I-1.11.1 27a5e771" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.4, released 2016/01/2
  5" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.11" (core procs from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade) RASTER (ras
  ter procs from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade)

I think maybe I'm affected by [this bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3633).

**UPDATE**:

I think it is relevant that I've migrated from PostGIS 2.1.8 in Postgres 9.3 to version 2.4.7.  Then migrated to Postgres 11 and PostGIS 2.4.7, and finally tried to version 2.5.2.